# Finding the nonlinear polarisation density for the Raman response from $\rm CO_2$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, raman-spectroscopy

Given the gas temperature $T$, the wavelength of the laser beam illuminating the gas, $ \lambda $ aswell as a diffusion coefficient, $\sigma $ and the susceptibility for the stokes transition $ \chi_{s} $. How can I find the nonlinear polarisation density under the assumption that the $\rm CO_2$ molecule can be modeled as a three mass spring system, and that the gas follows the Boltzmann distribution?

[image]

My idea was to use equation (15.1) and simply find the unknowns, being the constant $\dfrac{\partial\alpha}{\partial x}$, $x_0$ and $E_0$ but I'm having a hard time seeing how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Your model is too simple. You need to assign some charges to the system, to get something that interacts with EM radiation. The simplest Lorentz model is an harmonic oscillator with two oppositely charged particles, i.e. two masses connected by a spring and each having opposite charge. To get a realistic behaviour with relaxation of phase and damping of oscillations, your oscillators need to be damped in the model (terms linear in velocity). This model is well analyzed and documented, and is a good starting point to understand the theory of linear (and nonlinear) response.

Then calculate how this microscopic system with three masses carrying charges behaves in external harmonic field, especially where all the charges are, as function of external electric field and time. This allows you to express microscopic current density $\mathbf j_a$ due to molecule $a$, as function of macroscopic field.

If you want to take into account interactions between parts of molecules or between different molecules (which may be important for non-linear macroscopic response), with many components >2, this leads to matrix problems which is algebraically hard and one better uses computer to find oscillation amplitudes of such interacting multi-part systems.

Then derive estimation of macroscopic electric current density $\mathbf J$ due to gas of molecules, at some point on the line of a plane wave propagation, as some kind of average. The most direct way is to average microscopic current density of all molecules $\sum_a \mathbf j_a$ over the plane of constant phase of macroscopic electric field, taking into account all possible rotational orientations of the molecules.

Then infer the corresponding polarization (to $\mathbf J$), the usual relation (assuming no conduction and no magnetic effects) is $\mathbf J = \frac{\partial \mathbf P}{\partial t}$.

Then you can infer corresponding susceptibilities. The part of $P$ that is linear in macroscopic field amplitude $E_0$ is the so called "linear susceptibility", and the other parts dependent on that amplitude are "non-linear susceptibilities".

All this is a lengthy and subtle topic already with classical models, and to get a realistic spectra, one needs to assume convenient parameters for modes of oscillation that can be later fixed by experimental results. Finding these parameters theoretically is hard, more a topic for a thesis rather than for an SE answer.